# need a way to run intel 16 bit MASM on a 64 bit machine, is this possible?

Tags: masm

I am taking a computer architecture class, and we are learning assembly language on 16 bit machines. On-campus department labs have these machines available, but I want to be able to work on labs at home.

Where can I download MASM that can run 16bit code, I,m sure there is a way to do it, i just have to link 16 bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/), [dosemu](http://dosemu.sourceforge.net/), or something similar to emulate an old x86 DOS machine, and run your 16-bit code on that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 6 years ago, but to help others. Current MASM on Microsoft website is mainly for 32 and 64bit but you can get old versions here: http://bytepointer.com/masm/index.htm. and another one here http://www.masm32.com/licence.htm

I found that only old versions of MASM with FreeDOS, XP, DosBox etc will enable you to run the 16 bit code. You cant run 16bit executatable in a 64bit System.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: You can **build** a 16-bit MSDOS .obj file with every version. There are even 32-bit Windows versions of `LINK16.EXE`. You need DosBox to run the 16-bit .exe files in a 64-bit Windows system. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328941/3512216

Comment: You are very correct. Actually what I mean was the latest version from the Microsoft website is mainly for 32 and 64bits. I will add your link for completeness, just in case someone comes here later. I hope it is okay?

Comment: A link is okay in any case - even with a critical remark. This is the spirit of the WWW.